# android - onBackPressed() not working for me

Tags: android

I have a program. The first activity is a splash screen and the second is the log in and the third is a list view menu activity, and then 2 other activities.
The splash screen disappear after 3 seconds and if the log in check box remember me is checked, it goes directly to the menu page.
I override the `onBackPressed` function in the menu activity so that it will exit the program directly after the user click back from the menu. However, if I have gone through the other activities it doesn't exit; it goes to the previous activity in the stack and the dialog box doesn't pop up, although it actually does appear for a second no less and disappear right away.

Here is my  `onBackPressed` function

```
public void onBackPressed() {
    // super.onBackPressed();
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder.setMessage("Are you Sure want to close the Application..?")
        .setCancelable(false)
        .setTitle("EXIT")
        .setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                dialog.cancel();
            }
        })
        .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                finish();
            }
        });
    AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
    alert.show();
    //super.onBackPressed();
}
```

Comment: what's exactly your problem

Comment: wow, there are 6 1/2 line of text and I am not able to find any point. How about improving your grammar to a readable state?!

Comment: How about adding dots and commas for start. Somehow you can deal with grammar :)

Comment: the question is unclear. as @blackbelt asks pls edit your question and describe your problem

Comment: i am sorry its my first time :(
my problem is that the program doesnt exit it goes to the previous activity on the stack . 
and the AlertDialog doesnt even appear

Comment: @user2401745 take it easy. everyone has his firsttime

Comment: @user2401745 don't display a dialog on back button click. i guess it's a bad design coz i read it somewhere on SO answered by commonsware.

Comment: @User2401745 use system.exit(0) rather than finish();

Comment: @user2401745 you can use this Intent myIntent = new Intent(MyActivity.this, MainActivity.class);

 myIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
 startActivity(myIntent);
 finish(); on back button pressed inn your current activity when you back press you clear the activity stack and naviagate to MainActivity.

Comment: then how can i make it exit on back click the hole app not to go to the previous activity on the stack?

Comment: this code is working what exactly problem

Comment: @user2401745 would be nice if you still could clean up the question. Make some sentences out of the block of words

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Update - 19th June 2022**

The below answer is outdated. We can use the navigation architecture components with toolbar so the back navigation is handled for us or you should check https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-custom-back

For navigation architecture components check

https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-getting-started

Navigation components are available for compose as well
https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/navigation

**Old Answer** - Outdated

I would suggest you to use ActionBar as suggested by WarrenFaith in the comments below. Pls check the link below for more information

http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/navigation.html

Here's a tutorial for the same

http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidActionBar/article.html

You can use this. However this also seems to be a bad design. You can check the comments below to know why

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
        onBackPressed();
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}

public void onBackPressed() {
    Intent myIntent = new Intent(MyActivity.this, MainActivity.class);

    myIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    startActivity(myIntent);
    finish();
    return;
}
```

Onn back button pressed inn your current activity when you back press you clear the activity stack and naviagate to MainActivity.

Also i would suggest no to display a alert dialog on back button press. Its a bad design. You can search on SO. i read the same and was answered by commonsware

Comment: Wait a moment. You are talking about a "close"-dialog being a bad design but in the same moment you suggest to open a new Activity instead? Are you kidding me? This is even worse than a dialog asking if I hit the back button by accident... A back button should at least bring me *back* and not into a newly created activity!

Comment: @WarrenFaith i agree with what you say. I know by default it should work like that. But since the OP was asking for the same i posted it.

Comment: Still one of the worst UX experience you can create. I will therefore keep the down vote.

Comment: In fact that is where a so called "navigation" structure comes into the scene and tells you: "hey, you can use the back button, but if you want to go to home, just press the icon in my actionbar and you are back at home". Even the new SlideMenu would be a good UX solution. And yes: I would expect it to go 40 screens back as it is the reason the back button exists. Do you expect the back button in your browser to bring you to the start page? Where do you differ between "the user wants to go one step back" or "he wants to go all the way back"? I hope I made it clear...

Comment: @WarrenFaith its clear. I just wanted some clarification that's all. I am editing my answer

Comment: @WarrenFaith i edited my answer and provided to link to the user doc site. I went through the link. You are right its a bad design. thanks for letting me know. This will help me suggest better answer in the future for same kind of questions. Learnt something new

Comment: @WarrenFaith thanks for your support and detailed info of the topic

Comment: @WarrenFaith could you pls check this question and answer in the link. have i suggested in the right way http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16709618/how-to-close-all-activities-while-pressing-hardware-home-button/16709885#comment24055228_16709885

Answer (score 2):

You can override back button like this

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
        // write your code here
    }
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    super.onBackPressed();
    int count = getSupportFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount();
    Log.e("count", "is getBackStackEntryCount -> " + count);
    for (int i = 0; i < count; ++i) {
        getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStackImmediate();
        Log.e("getBackStack", "IS REMOVED " + i);
    }
    // toolbar.setTitle("Dashboard");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Removing the finish(); after every startActivity(); will allow for proper navigation instead of having to call finish(); that executes the method onDestroy() . Thank u . No need to override the onBackPressed function . Use finish() only when your activity is no longer needed and should be closed .

Comment: Its better than having to write a onPressedBack method for every activity for navigation let alone all the Alert dialogs . just saying .

Comment: Just use finish in all the activities you don't want the user going back to such as a login

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead of `onBackPressed` if you are using `android.support.v7.app.ActionBar`:

```
    @Override
    public boolean onSupportNavigateUp() {
        // do your stuff

        return super.onSupportNavigateUp();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution for onBackKeypress() and show Dialog.
if you use any method like onkeyDown OR onKeyUp , in that please check Back key is not used in that. if used than overide that key or simply removed from there.